# Retrieve all 'data' properties of json data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to access to all the data from a json provided by movie database api, but I don't understand how to retrieve it.
The console log give me an "data is not defined" error.

So here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready (function(){

    var key = 'api key provided';

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie'+key+'&query=Minions',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            format:'json'
        },
        error: $('#result').append("errore"),
        success: function(data){$('#result').append("ok")}
    });
    var jsonData=data.results.original_title;               
    //this give me a data is not provided
});
```

Here a portion of json:
[image]

Let's assume that I only want to access to the `release_date` propriety, how can I achieve this?

Comment: results its an array.... which result you need?? result[?]

Comment: You seem to be accessing data outside the callback function. `$.ajax` is aynchronous. So `data` can only be accessed in `$.ajax.success` (where you typed `.append("ok")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` not is defined out of `$.ajax()` closure, you need to move the code to success handler like, then loop through the JSON `data.results`.

```
success: function(data){
        $('#result').append("ok");
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
            console.log('Release date is' + result.release_date);
        });
}
```

alternatively, you can define a variable, then update that variable in `success` handler of `$.ajax()`

```
var ajaxResponse; 
$.ajax({
    /* skipped lines*/
    success: function(data){
         ajaxResponse = data
    }
});
```

Comment: And tell jQuery to make a syncronous request